# How to detect mouse click position in Xamarin.Forms using WPF?

Tags: wpf, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin.Forms with WPF, how do I capture a mouse click event and get the mouse position relative to the clicked element?

I've tried using ClickGestureRecognizer but can't get the event to fire.

```
<BoxView>
    <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
        <ClickGestureRecognizer Clicked="ClickGestureRecognizer_OnClicked" />
    </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
</BoxView>
```

Perhaps this is not implemented for WPF at this time, or I am using it wrongly. TapGestureRecognizer does fire, but I can't see a way to get the mouse location when using that.

Comment: I had no luck with the ClickGestureRecognizer (and TapGestureRecognizer doesn't provide the click location) but by modifying the TouchTrackingEffect Sample I was able to capture mouse events using an Effect. This github repository shows the MouseClickEffect library and the WPF specific code.
Github: https://github.com/Avacee/Effects There's also a small demo showing how you use the Effect via XAML or Code Behind.
It's WPF only (at the moment) as that's what I needed as Touch worked on UWP,iOS and Android.

Comment: The TouchTracking Sample should you wish to create your own Mouse Click Effect
Touch Effect:  https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Effects/TouchTrackingEffect

and the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/touch-tracking